# How can I delete just the parent key for a Firebase value?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am fairly new to using Firebase and I am struggling to access just the parent key to delete the value.

I am currently trying to access the parent key using the following code:

```
if let exerciseName = exercises[indexPath.row].exerciseName {

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("userExercises")

    ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "exerciseName").queryEqual(toValue: exerciseName).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            print(snapshot.ref)

    })

}
```

My data structure looks like:

[image: this image].

But when I print the values out if there is another user with the same `exerciseName` in the database it prints out all of the parent keys.

How can I only delete the record I have selected to delete?

When I `print(snapshot)` the result is:

```
Snap (-KWw9hg2Uiyo9_cj7TAy) {
    bodyPart = Back;
    exerciseName = "Test 2";
    userId = 8rHmyTxdocTEvk1ERiiavjMUYyD3;
}
Snap (-KWwAGd3t9vsW0LHKtV1) {
    bodyPart = Arms;
    exerciseName = "Test 2";
    userId = PO8p0UoqqHOas3D9Ise8CgWT3PN2;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the what 'print(snapshot)' says.

Comment: It prints out two values:
"tracker-test-c61e6.firebaseio.com/userExercises/-KWw9hg2Uiyo9_cj7TAy"

"tracker-test-c61e6.firebaseio.com/userExercises/-KWwAGd3t9vsW0LHKtV1"

Comment: NO, post what `print(snaphot)` says in your question, edit it. not the snapshot.ref

Comment: When you initially fetch your user's data you need to save the record id (see below my answer). Then all you need to do is just delete that record ... without any querying.

If you never show userExcercises of User A to User B, you should restructure your data ...

Comment: Thank you for this it has helped massively, how would you recommend I restructure my data as I never intend on showing users custom exercises to  one another?

Comment: your welcome. I added a suggestion to my answer. please upvote if it helps you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("userExercises")        
    let filteredRef = // do some query,sorting ...

    filteredRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        for item in snapshot.children {
            guard let itemSnapshot = item as? FIRDataSnapshot else { break }
            guard let dict = itemSnapshot.value as? NSDictionary else { break }

            let id = itemSnapshot.key // this is the record id of an exercise !
        }
    }
```

To delete one of your records:

```
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("userExcercises").child(record_id) // see above how to fetch the id
    ref.removeValue()
```

I would suggest you restructure your userExcercises like so:

```
{
    "userExcercises" : {
        "<USER-ID>" : {
            "<EXCERCISE-ID>" : {
                "bodyPart" : "Back",
                "excerciseName" : "Test02"
            },
            // lots of more excercises for this user ...
        },
        // lots of more users ...
     }
}
```

to be clear: USER-ID is the uid of the authenticated user, EXCERCISE-ID is a autogenerated ( childByAutoId() ) id